# What language should I learn to make 2D turn-based video games?

Tags: 2d

I want to make 2 dimensional turn-based games for the PC. Something like early Final Fantasy or Chrono Trigger.  Is C++ the only plausible option? I keep getting told that C++ is the language of choice for games, but is this the case even for 2D, turn-based games?  Are any other languages good for this sort of thing?  I'm really big on clean, readable, extendible code, so a language that fosters that sort of thing would be great.

Doing this for fun, not business.  Java is the only language I really know well right now.

By the way, this is my first question and I'm a noob.  I read the FAQ, but if I'm doing anything noobish anyway, then I'm sorry.

Answer (score 7):

Just about any language will do.

C, C++, Java, C# - they all have good supporting libraries.

If you know Java, stick with it, find a good 2D library for it and play around.

[Here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/index.html) is the official Java 2D Graphics tutorial from Sun.

[Here](http://geosoft.no/graphics/) is one graphics library for Java.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a software *3D engine* in [javascript if you want](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/wolf/).  It won't run fast.   The reason people use C++ is because, generally, you get best performance with a good compiler compiling to machine code.  That said, I've seen plenty of games (2D and 3D) written in Java, Actionscript, Python and a whole host of other languages.  You can use whichever language you want but be aware you are most likely to get best performance using *assembler*, provided you know what you are doing ;)

Comment: So not gonna give a reason the downvote?  I'm all up for *constructive* criticism ...

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted you, but it looks like you might have got the downvote because you are talking about 3D when the question was about 2D.

Comment: I think he cited 3D to highlight the performance aspect, and then went on to explicitly state both 2D and 3D. @Goz - This keeps happening to me all the time as well...

Comment: Not complaining or anything, since I really appreciate answers, but I personally found it confoozling.  Maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 2):

For 2D games, especially turn based, any language will do. Even languages as high level as Python and Ruby are perfectly fine, and have relevant libraries (e.g. [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html)).

Comment: Take a look at pyGEngine. It is an extension for Pygame for making graphics easier.

Answer (score 2):

Take a hard look at C# and the XNA Framework developed by Microsoft. The XNA Framework allows you to build games for the desktop, XBOX, and ZUNE.

Comment: As of 30 JUL 13, I would use C# and the SharpDX Toolkit @ sharpdx.org

Answer (score 1):

C++ is not the **only** option, but it has a whole bunch of great graphics (including 2D) libraries that would simplify development.

This is a good place to start: http://www.thefreecountry.com/sourcecode/graphics.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Well if you like Java, Slick2D is a great library built on top of LWJGL (LightWeight Java Game Library) I would check both of them out:

[LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org)

[Slick2D](http://slick.ninjacave.com)

P.S. LWJGL works with 3D games too, it's what Minecraft was built on.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Java for a 2D game because it already has graphics libraries like JFrame, and JPanel!